# put inputs in session with laravel cross domain

Tags: session, laravel, request, cross-domain, put

I want to put params received into session, everything works when post request is send by me in the same domain. The problem is that when post request is send from external domain (params are correctly send ), Session::put doesnt work. Because post request is send from external domain that i haven't access i can't see what's wrong...
I noticed that session id change everytime a post request to 'coupon' is send from external domain.

```
Route::post('coupon', 'CouponController@postSelections');

public function postSelections(){
    Session::put('inputs', Input::all());
}
```

result :

```
array (size=5)
  '_token' => string '****' (length=40)
  'flash' => 
    array (size=2)
      'old' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'new' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  '****' => int 2
```

Someone has an idea?

Comment: `Session` uses terminable middleware. which means it writes the data after response has been already sent to the browser. Send some response and then test again. Should work. _Or_, call the `terminate()` manually.

Comment: i use 4.2 version, its the same ?

Comment: yes. for 4.2, session also is `written` in same way.

Comment: i don't see a terminate function in laravel api

Comment: with return 1; doesnt work too :/